# Is there a way to get the transaction hash from a contract address during contract creation using Ethers js or Web3 js?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I've tried getting the transaction count of the smart contract and tried to return the first transaction of the contract which is during its creation. But currently I can't find anything for this. Need helppp

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this using web3.js or ethers.js, but is not very efficient:

### web3.js or ethers.js

Use web3.js or ethers.js with a custom script to iterate each transaction receipt in a block to identify the transaction that created your desired contract. This is easy to achieve but fairly inefficient.

The following is an example in web3.js. that uses the `eth_getBlockReceipts` method to inspect each receipt in a block (starting from the latest block). Contract creator transactions will have a `to` field = `null`. From there, it compares the address; if it matches, it means it found the creation transaction.

```js
const Web3 = require("web3");
const NODE_URL = "CHAINSTACK_NODE_URL";
const web3 = new Web3(NODE_URL);

web3.extend({
  property: "eth",
  methods: [
    {
      name: "getBlockReceipts",
      call: "eth_getBlockReceipts",
      params: 1,
      inputFormatter: [web3.extend.formatters.inputDefaultBlockNumberFormatter],
      outputFormatter: null,
    },
  ],
});

async function findContractCreationTransaction(contractAddress) {
  const latestBlockNumber = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();
  contractAddress = contractAddress.toLowerCase();

  console.log(`Starting block: ${latestBlockNumber}`);

  for (let i = latestBlockNumber; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(`Inspecting block ${i}`);
    const receipts = await web3.eth.getBlockReceipts(i);

    if (receipts) {
      for (const receipt of receipts) {
        if (receipt.contractAddress && receipt.contractAddress.toLowerCase() === contractAddress) {
          console.log("Found it!");
          const txHash = receipt.transactionHash
          return txHash;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return null;
}

async function main() {
  const contractAddress = "YOUR_SMART_CONTRACT"; // Replace with your contract address
  console.log("Looking for contract creation...");
  const creationTransaction = await findContractCreationTransaction(contractAddress);

  if (creationTransaction) {
    console.log("Transaction Hash:", creationTransaction);
  } else {
    console.log("Contract creation transaction not found.");
  }
}

main().catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

The `findContractCreationTransaction` function takes a contract address as input and searches for the transaction that created the contract by iterating through the blocks in reverse order (starting from the latest block).

> The eth_getblockReceipt method is super useful but only available on the Erigon client.
>
> Extra resources on eth_getBlockReceipts:
>
> - The Chainstack API docs have a good description and examples (I built those API pages as disclosure): [eth_getBlockReceipts API](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-getblockreceipts)
> - I wrote a [guide about eth_getBlockReceipts](https://docs.chainstack.com/docs/uncovering-the-power-of-ethgetblockreceipts) and how to use it.
> - If you don't have access to an archive node running the Erigon client, I also wrote a guide on how to [build an emulator for eth_getBlockReceipts](https://docs.chainstack.com/docs/expanding-your-blockchain-horizons-the-eth_getblockreceipts-emulator)

This is for finding the contract creation transaction in case you have the smart contract that was already created.

You can also monitor new blocks for contract creation in a similar way. This is explained in the article about eth_getBlockReceipts.

### Bonus more efficient way

If you want a more efficient way to find the contract creator transaction, you could use the Etherscan API, which already indexed the data.

You could use a combination of both; web3.js and eth_getBlockReceipts to find new contracts as the blocks are added to the chain and the Etherscan API to find old ones.

Here is an example of the call:

```sh
curl --location 'https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getcontractcreation&contractaddresses=0xB83c27805aAcA5C7082eB45C868d955Cf04C337F%2C0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45%2C0xe4462eb568E2DFbb5b0cA2D3DbB1A35C9Aa98aad%2C0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7%2C0xf5b969064b91869fBF676ecAbcCd1c5563F591d0&apikey=YourApiKeyToken' \
--header 'accept: application/json'
```

And a docs reference:

- [Get Contract Creator and Creation Tx Hash](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/contracts#get-contract-creator-and-creation-tx-hash)

Comment: However the first method can't deal with a contract that was created by another contract. Those addresses weren't recorded on transaction receipts.

Answer (score 0):

you can catch smart Contract events with web3.eth.subscribe and get timestamp of event,after that you can sort transaction based on timeStap and find your target transaction.
read [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.2/web3-eth-subscribe.html) for better understanding.